# Can I configure my Dev C++ or any other C++ compatible IDE to automatically include some code in every new source file that I create?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I have been working on Dev c++ for a while, and often most of the source files I create ,generally include same header file declarations, #define directives and even some of the variables declarations. So is there a way to include all of this code for each new source file that I create, so that manual copying and pasting job is minimized

Comment: Make common.h in which you include all those and just include common.h? (In VS theres a thing called precompiled headers which is similar)

Comment: I believe in eclipse you can change the templates...

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian Confirmed, you can do that in eclipse.

Comment: @OP _"so that manual copying and pasting job is minimized"_ I'd strongly discourage that the either way, it's error prone and even considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: @OP and above, it is a very bad idea to do that. Why not just include a header file; it is just a single line. Anyone else looking at your code will be very confused.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse you can edit Templates

[image]

[Link](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_code_temp.htm&resultof=%22cdt%22%20%22templates%22%20%22templat%22)

Answer (score 1):

Dev-C++ I believe has GCC/MinGW underneath

Thus, you put all your common defs, ..., into one include file (lets call it config.h) and pass down
GCC option -include

```
-include file

Process file as if "#include "file"" appeared as the first line of the primary source file.
```